# How should I add `broker_url` setting for Airflow Celery Worker in Airflow 2.8.0?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, celery

I'm trying to setup Celery with Redis for Airflow 2.8.0 installation on my Ubuntu machine and I couldn't understand where I should put `broker_url` setting.

If you examine `airflow.cfg`, you'll notice that there is no Celery section of settings in it.
[Official docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-celery/stable/configurations-ref.html) are unclear - it says I should find configuration file of Celery in airflow.providers.celery (`~/airflow/airflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/celery`), but there is no configuration file here:

> The configuration embedded in provider packages started to be used as
> of Airflow 2.7.0. Previously the configuration was described and
> configured in the Airflow core package - so if you are using Airflow
> below 2.7.0, look at Airflow documentation for the list of available
> configuration options that were available in Airflow core.

So the questions are:

1. Where should I put `broker_url` setting for Airflow 2.8.0?
2. What configuration file Airflow Celery Worker use by default?
   If I start it with command `airflow celery worker` it will write that transport is redis://redis:6379/0

```
(airflow) my@comp:~/airflow$ airflow celery worker
[2023-12-30 11:41:27 +0000] [215202] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-12-30 11:41:27 +0000] [215202] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:8793 (215202)
[2023-12-30 11:41:27 +0000] [215202] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-12-30 11:41:27 +0000] [215203] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 215203
[2023-12-30 11:41:27 +0000] [215204] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 215204
 
 -------------- celery@comp v5.3.6 (emerald-rush)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.0-91-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2023-12-30 11:41:27
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         airflow.providers.celery.executors.celery_executor:0x7fd684150b50
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     postgresql+psycopg2://airflow_user:**@localhost:5432/airflow_db
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> default          exchange=default(direct) key=default
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the content below to the end of airflow.cfg file:

```
[celery]
broker_url = redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
```

This helped to override broker URL for Celery.
Not sure this is the solution (more like workaround), but I couldn't find where to place this setting.